# Cell Edit Issue with Prime React

Tags: reactjs, primereact

I was using 9.2.3 version of Primereact. And I could able to edit datatable cells no problem. Like I mean like below picture for example. If I entered data and if  I clicked outside of the cell it was saving to table. But with latest version of Primereact which is 9.6.2 I can only save data with enter button. I mean If I entered data in cell and clicked outside of the cell and not hit enter in keyboard. The data which I wanted to save is lost. How can I achieve that with latest version of PrimeReact?
[image]

Below code is my datatable part. The problem is with oncelleditcomplete. On that event new value with 9.6.2 version is empty. If I revert back to 9.2.3 I can able to get newvalue with oncelleditcomplete event. I mean if I clicked outside of the cell.

```
   <DataTable id="prDetailListTable" value={prDetailList} showGridlines editMode="cell" style={{}} tableStyle={{ minWidth: '50rem' }} header={addNewPrDetailHeader}>
                                {columns.map(({ field, header }) => {
                                    return (
                                        <Column
                                            key={field}
                                            field={field}
                                            header={header}
                                            headerClassName="text-900 font-semibold text-xl"
                                            style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}
                                            editor={(options) => cellEditor(options)}
                                            onCellEditComplete={onCellEditComplete}
                                            onBeforeCellEditShow={onBeforeCellEditShow}
                                            onBeforeCellEditHide={onBeforeCellEditHide}
                                            onCellEditCancel={onCellEditCancel}
                                            onCellEditInit={onCellEditInit}
                                        />
                                    );
                                })}
                            </DataTable>
```

And my oncelleditcomplete method like below. If I print 'e' with new version of PrimeReact and If I clicked outside of the cell this new value comes as empty.

```
 const onCellEditComplete = (e) => {
        let { rowData, newValue, field, newRowData, props, rowIndex, originalEvent: event } = e;
        console.log(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is an issue with 9.6.2 version.
i see that it is fixed in 9.6.4